# Rotate a button in a javascript interface

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Please have a look at [this](http://pulsewave.net/player) page

Try to click one of big buttons on the panel and to move your mouse on the y axis. The buttons start rotating as they should. Now, leave your mouse and click them again: why the heck do they insist into getting back in their original position?!

Here's the code snippet related to the button rotation. Please note that the code executed in the draw loop is called every 30ms.

```
// method
Button.prototype.Rotate = function(yDrag){
this.rotation =  - (yDrag - this.rotationYClick) / 80 
}

// draw loop
function drawLoop() {

if (buttons[n].roating == true && mousePressed == true)
buttons[n].Rotate(mousePosition_y)
else
buttons[n].roating = false
} // end draw loop

// fired ONLY ONCE when mouse is clicked
function mouseDown() {
buttons[n].roating = true
buttons[n].rotationYClick = mousePosition_y
}
```

I've intentionally avoided to post most of the code as I'm sure the problem lies in these lines.

Code explanation: when you click on a button, the position of the mouse is stored in the variable `rotationYClick` of the class `Button`. While you drag your mouse, the mouse position is constantly compared to the stored value: the distance of your current mouse position from the point which you clicked will determine how much the button rotate. Problem is, as you click it again the rotation is set back to zero. How to solve?!

[Here's](http://pulsewave.net/player/try.html) one of my failed tries by changing the method

```
// method
Button.prototype.Rotate = function(yDrag){
this.rotation +=  - (yDrag - this.rotationYClick) / 80 
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are setting this.rotation. Use += instead of =

The problem is that you reevaluate the rotation on each drag without taking into consideration the present rotation angle of the button.

**EDIT**

Ok, so its not *that* simple :)
Basically you'll have to keep two variables. One for the original rotation angle, and one that represents the current rotation. So, it becomes something like this:

```
this.rotation = this._originalRotation - ((yDrag-this.rotationYClick)/80);
```

and `mouseDown` becomes:

```
// fired ONLY ONCE when mouse is clicked
function mouseDown() {
    buttons[n].roating = true
    buttons[n].rotationYClick = mousePosition_y
    buttons[n]._originalRotation = this.rotation;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that already, but when I do it starts rotating crazely fast! Let me upload also this try so that you can see... 2 seconds please.

Comment: also: `roating` should be `rotating`... just saying :)

Comment: ahahahah! you're right, forgive my bad spelling. I'm trying this solution, give me a sec...

Comment: oh man! you can't use "this" in the mouseDown() function. I just copied and pasted your code without using my brain and got crazy cause it wasn't working. I've edited your answer. Now it works perfectly, thanks a lot for your kind help! :)